# moving my DeviceToken to my database

Tags: php, ios, devicetoken

I am trying to move my DeviceToken to my database this is what I have tried:

I have the code inside my AppDelegate:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"content---%@", token);
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.co.uk/push/push.php"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:token forKey:@"token"]; 
}
```

and for www.example.co.uk/push/push.php I have the php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","yyy","zzzz");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO active_users (device_token) VALUES ('$_POST[token]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I am receiving no errors. But nothing is appearing in my database.

I made a form to post to the php and it works fine. So there is nothing wrong with the php.

The `ASIFormDataRequest` is properly imported as there are no errors.

But I am still receiving nothing to my database? - Literally nothing **not** just an empty cell. Which means that the php is not even being "requested"?

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding at the end of your code:

```
[request startSynchronous];
```

You are creating the request but you aren't sending it.
If you need to get the response, do

```
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
NSString *response = [request responseString];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO active_users (device_token) VALUES ('".$_POST['token']."')";
```

Comment: Still nothing appearing!